# How to retrieve form data in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

This is my first Ember App and I could really use some help. I have created a sign in page on which there are two input fields for each player's name. The goal is to capture each name upon clicking submit and pushing them to a model (or store?) so I can retrieve them from another template.

Here is the form template:

```
{{!-- templates/signin.hbs --}}
<div class="enterNames">
  <h2>Player Sign In</h2>
  <form {{action save on="submit"}} >
    <div class="p1input">
      {{input type="text" valueBinding="p1name" placeholder="Player 1" cols="60" rows="1"}}
    </div>
    <div class="p2input">
      {{input type="text" valueBinding="p2name" placeholder="Player 2" cols="60" rows="1"}}
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Is this something that would be done using a model hook within a route? If so, what would that route look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define p2name property in `signin.js` controller and bind it to input helper like below,

```
{{input type="text" value={{p2name}} placeholder="Player 2" cols="60" rows="1"}}
```

So whenever you type value in text field that value will be available in `p2name`  property. so you can inject this controller in another template by using the below in corresponding controller file,

```
signCont: Ember.inject.controller('signin')
```

You can retrieve properties in template using `{{signCont.p2name}}` and in js file `this.get('signCont.p2name')`. Remember you can inject controller only in controller not in other places.

EDIT: define property just like defining properties in ember object. I created [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f49f8706cff736aacbb0f7da8ae597da?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C&route=%2Fgame) for you. do check it out using the `/game` url

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Would you mind elaborating on how to define that p2name property in the controller?

Comment: @BrittShroyer updated sample ember-twiddle do check it out. I am displaying `p2name` property from application controller to game controller

Comment: It's working. The example really helped. Thanks again.